# How to store long text (about 4000000 character) in SQL Server 2014 by Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

When I try to save my `Article` object that contains a field of string type (about 4000000 character) in a database table that maps to a `nvarchar(max)` column, Entity Framework could not send the value of that string from C# application to the database.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is my model

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Authors { get; set; }
}
```

here is the saving part

```
private void EditDatabase(Article article)
{
    try
    {
        var db = new ArticleContext();
        db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: You should make the column type `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: i use sqlserver2014 and my column type is nvarchar(max) but cant save this long text

Comment: Can you please post some code? What is the error?

Comment: i dont have any error ,just cant store long data in database with entityframework

Comment: How do you know you cant'? Please post the code where you are trying to save the entity.

Comment: public class Article
    {
      
        public int Id { get; set; }
       
        public string Authors { get; set; }

}    this is my model ,author have a long data(4000000 character) that cant save into database

Comment: private void EditDatabase(Article article)
        {
            try
            {
                var db = new ArticleContext();
                db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                db.Dispose();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }

        } this is edit database method

Comment: You shouldn't post code in comments. You should add these code to the question. I did it for you.

Comment: You are catching the exception and doing nothing with it. Try to debug your `EditDatabase` method and check for any exception thrown.

Comment: it dont have any exception

Comment: It is unlikely that you don't get any exceptions. Have you tried saving anything with a shorter text and did that work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you just create that `Article` object before? Or did you retrieve it from the database?

Anyway - you're just changing it's state - but you're not **attaching** it to the context - therefore it won't be saved:

```
private void EditDatabase(Article article)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new ArticleContext())
        {
            // assuming you're *created* that "article" from scratch  
            // then you need to **ADD** it to the context first, to save it!
            db.Articles.Add(article);

            // this won't be needed
            // db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }  
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        // Log your exception
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If that `article` has already been stored in the database and handled by another context before being passed into `EditDatabase`, then you must **attach** that pre-existing database object to the new context you create and set its `State` to `Modified`:

```
private void EditDatabase(Article article)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new ArticleContext())
        {
            // assuming this "article" has been loaded from the database
            // by another context before, then you need to **ATTACH** it
            // to this current context before you can save it here!
            db.Articles.Attach(article);
            db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }  
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        // Log your exception
    }
}
```

Comment: i have more fields in my model that store in database by step .it means that some of them add to database first, then i search again and others like "authors" add again,for this reason i use "db.Entry(article).State" for edit

Comment: @mahtab: updated my response with the scenario that the `article` already exists and has been loaded elsewhere to be saved here in this method

Comment: `Entry` will attach the entity to the context.